# touch calibration not possible with wayland

Tags: x11, wayland

In older fedora versions I can do the following:

```
xinput --list
```

find my device: "Advanced Silicon S.A. CoolTouch(TM) System"

and can simply set the props I need with:

```
xinput set-prop 'Advanced Silicon S.A. CoolTouch(TM) System' --type=float 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 0.533333333333333, 0, 0.466666666666667, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1
```

But now, `xinput list` did not show my any real devices, only some mystery generic ones as this:

```
 ⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
 ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
 ⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:14                      id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
 ⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:14             id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
 ⎜   ↳ xwayland-touch:14                        id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
 ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                    id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
     ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard              id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
     ↳ xwayland-keyboard:14                     id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

So I only see some mystery wayland pseudo devices.

With `libinput-list-devices` I can see my touch device, but I can not find any documentation how I can configure devices for libinput. All docs tell my that it can be done with `xinput` with is not true for wayland on fedora. Any idea?

Q: How can I configure input devices on wayland in fedora 25.

Update fedora 33:
There is still no support for touch calibration in wayland nor gnome. If we see, that some distributions are plan to drop X11 and only support wayland, we will se the loss of linux touch display support.

Answer (score 0):

In Wayland, input configuration is entirely up to the compositor/desktop environment ([source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput#Configuratio)). If your desktop (presumably Gnome) doesn't provide a way of doing some configuration, then that configuration can not be done. There tools to configure Gnome beyond the standard Gnome settings, such at gnome-tweek-tool, which may expose the options you want. There may even be config files you can edit, I'm not sure, but you definitely need a Gnome specific solution.